# increasing the Field of View or zooming out more on Android java

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I have a video editing app that requires a wide angel on the camera.
How could I achieve a wider angle on the camera or the preview, I have tried zooming out using the linear zoom method - this made a very minor difference - and the zoomRatio method, but had no success. The effect that I am trying to achieve is very much similar to when once chooses 0.5 zoom on your built in android camera app. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated!
I am using the following libaries:

````
    def cameraxVersion = "1.1.0-alpha05"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${cameraxVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${cameraxVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${cameraxVersion}"

    // CameraX View class
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha25'```

Here is an example of my code:
````

```
// cameraManager to interact with camera devices
  cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

  // Exception is handled, because to check whether
  // the camera resource is being used by another
  // service or not.
  try {
      // O means back camera unit,
      // 1 means front camera unit
      getCameraID = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];

      CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(getCameraID);


       Log.d(TAG, "charactersistcsX: " + characteristics.toString());

  } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }

  camProvider = cameraProvider;

  Log.d(TAG, "startCameraX: " + camProvider.getAvailableCameraInfos());

  cameraProvider.unbindAll();

  Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();

  preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

  previewView.setImplementationMode(PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE);

  // Setup.
  CameraController controller = new LifecycleCameraController(RecordVideo.this);

  previewView.setController(controller);

  imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
  .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
  .build();

  videoCapture = new VideoCapture.Builder()
  .setVideoFrameRate(60)
  //.setDefaultResolution(new Size(1080, 1920))
  .setTargetResolution(new Size(1080, 1920))
  .build();
```

Comment: I am afraid not all devices would allow you to to reduce zoom below 1.0. Anything below 1.0 is wide angle camera. You can try to set to a value below 1.0 and if you are lucky(if device lets 3rd party apps use wide angle), you will get the wide angle camera. Otherwise, you will get 1.0. Which is the main camera's minimum. And yes, built in camera apps are whitelisted to use this api. They can access to wide angle camera. Does not mean you can use it too though :(